# strange results after creating a loop to string

Tags: r

As part of a bigger solution I try to create names that are different for each other by one digit.For example: SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day**3**_BaseLine and SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day**6**_BaseLine.
I created a loop to do it but I got a strange results: Instead of getting only two results I got 6 results, the first one is good and also the third one but I don't understand how I get the NA's and also the six'th result.Also I thought that the first result will be "SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day3_BaseLine" and not "SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day3_BaseLine" but the oppsite occured.

```
for(i in c(3,6)){ p[i]<-paste("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day",i,"_BaseLine",sep="")}
> p
[1] "SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day6_BaseLine" NA                                 "SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day3_BaseLine"
[4] NA                                  NA                                  "SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day6_BaseLine"
```

Comment: From the code you supplied, `p[1]` should be `NA` as well. You haven't shown how you initialise `p`. The reason you are getting `NA` in the remaining entries is that you haven't specified these values. Try for example `v <- "a"` and then `v[1:2]` or `v[100]`. These values are `NA` but no "out of index" error is thrown, it's just how R works.

Comment: The result vector p has 6 results, including the NA results, because you loop through index 3 and index 6, this implies that the vector should have at least 6 entries, even if it began as an empty vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code you are creating an array with 6 elements:

`p[3] <- SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day3_BaseLine`

and

`p[6] <- SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day6_BaseLine`

So `R` thinks you need also the element with index 1,2,4,5.

Try this code:

```
p <- NA # first I reset p
index <- 1 # this will be the index
for(i in c(3,6)){ 
  p[index]<-paste("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day",i,"_BaseLine",sep="")
  index <- index + 1
}
p
```